# Bifurcation and ridge ending point

Tags: java, image, image-processing, imagej

Is there any way to find Bifurcation point and ridge ending point in a Image (hand, vein), by using a Java code only not Matlab etc.?  Can I achieve this by ImageJ Library of Java?

Comment: @RyanAmos  I prefer [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) (link).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ooh fancy. I will have to start using that from now on!

Answer (score 1):

A scientific description you find in [Minutiae Extraction from Fingerprint Images](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1201/1201.1422.pdf). 
Some algorithms are implemented in [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) see the segmentation section.

The OpenCV library can be linked to java using JNI.

Comment: Hi stacker.I am not very much comfortable with OpenCv. I will use the method later .I hope I will get my expectation.Thanks a lot for help me out from such thing.

Comment: The link is broken, can you provide some other resources?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/search.html?q=Segmentation&check_keywords=yes&area=default @jay

Answer (score 1):

There is an ImageJ plugin that could help you to do that:

[AnalyzeSkeleton](http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/AnalyzeSkeleton)
(for the source see [here](http://fiji.sc/AnalyzeSkeleton_.java) )

You can extract branching points and endpoints with the help of its `SkeletonResult` class.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to help me out I went through AnalyzeSkeleton and got the result in SekeletonResult Response by Using IJ. for this I have used IJ.run(imp, "Skeletonize", "");

```
 // Initialize AnalyzeSkeleton_
  AnalyzeSkeleton_ skel = new AnalyzeSkeleton_();
 skel.calculateShortestPath = true;
 skel.setup("", imp);

 // Perform analysis in silent mode
 // (work on a copy of the ImagePlus if you don't want it displayed)
 // run(int pruneIndex, boolean pruneEnds, boolean shortPath, ImagePlus origIP, boolean silent, boolean verbose)
 SkeletonResult skelResult = skel.run(AnalyzeSkeleton_.NONE, false, true, null, true, false);

 // Read the results
 Object shortestPaths[] = skelResult.getShortestPathList().toArray();
 double branchLengths[] = skelResult.getAverageBranchLength();
 int branchNumbers[] = skelResult.getBranches();

 long totalLength = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < branchNumbers.length; i++) {
     totalLength += branchNumbers[i] * branchLengths[i];
 }

 double cumulativeLengthOfShortestPaths = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < shortestPaths.length; i++) {
     cumulativeLengthOfShortestPaths +=(Double)shortestPaths[i];
 }
  System.out.println("totalLength "+totalLength);
  System.out.println("cumulativeLengthOfShortestPaths "+cumulativeLengthOfShortestPaths);
System.out.println("getNumOfTrees "+skelResult.getNumOfTrees());
System.out.println("getAverageBranchLength "+skelResult.getAverageBranchLength().length);
System.out.println("getBranches "+skelResult.getBranches().length);
System.out.println("getEndPoints "+skelResult.getEndPoints().length);
System.out.println("getGraph "+skelResult.getGraph().length);
System.out.println("getJunctions "+skelResult.getJunctions().length);
System.out.println("getJunctionVoxels "+skelResult.getJunctionVoxels().length);
System.out.println("getListOfEndPoints "+skelResult.getListOfEndPoints().size());
System.out.println("getListOfJunctionVoxels "+skelResult.getListOfJunctionVoxels().size());
System.out.println("getMaximumBranchLength "+skelResult.getMaximumBranchLength().length);
System.out.println("getNumberOfVoxels "+skelResult.getNumberOfVoxels().length);
System.out.println("getQuadruples "+skelResult.getQuadruples().length); this method .but I am not able to find which method in Skeleton Result class returns bifuraction point could you please help me little more thanks Amar
```

Comment: Hi jan Many thanks to help me out.one little more help I am able to get SkeletonResult class responcs by above implemented code.but which method in SkeletonResult class return Bifuraction and edning point.there is one method Endpoint in skeletonResult class but for every image it return only 1

Comment: Can I get number of bifurcation point and ridges points from an image in java? Or I can get it from SkeletonResult class?